IpRateLimiting is not taking specific endpoint rules
I am using .Net 8 WebApi project. I am trying to implement IpRateLimiting feature for my webapi.
I have defined rule for "*:/api/values" endpoint as 4 requests within 1s. But this rule is not getting executed. It is always taking the rule(3 requests within 1s). Any idea on this ?
Sample Code Link: Source code Link
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "IpRateLimitingSettings": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "RealIpHeader": "X-Real-IP",
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*:/api/values",
        "Period": "1s",
        "Limit": 4
      },
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "1s",
        "Limit": 3
      }
    ]
  }
}


The following global rule is three times per second，
  {
    "Endpoint": "*",
    "Period": "1s",
    "Limit": 3
  }

will override the rule of "*:/api/values", which is four times per second.
  {
    "Endpoint":  "*:/api/values",
    "Period": "1s",
    "Limit": 4
  }

Test setting
"GeneralRules": [
  {
    "Endpoint":  "*:/api/values",
    "Period": "1s",
    "Limit": 3
  },
  {
    "Endpoint": "*",
    "Period": "1s",
    "Limit": 4
  }
]

The limit value for the global rule should be greater than that for other rules to work.

